# Facing error while using render in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, relationship

I am having 2 models:

app/models/employee.rb:

```
class Employee < User
    has_many :insurances 
end
```

app/models/insurance.rb:

```
 class Insurance < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :employee
    end
```

app/controllers/employees_controller.rb:

```
class EmployeesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_employee, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :employee_params, only: [:create, :update]
  # GET /employees
  # GET /employees.json
  def index
    @employees = Employee.all
  end

  # GET /employees/1
  # GET /employees/1.json

  def show
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /employees/new
  def new
    @employee = Employee.new
  end

  # GET /employees/1/edit
  def edit
     @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /employees
  # POST /employees.json
  def create
    @employee = Employee.new(employee_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.save
        format.html { redirect_to employees_url, notice: "#{@employee.first_name} was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :index, status: :created, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /employees/1
  # PATCH/PUT /employees/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @employee.update(employee_params)
        format.html { redirect_to employees_url, notice: "#{@employee.first_name} was successfully updated."}
        format.json { render :index, status: :ok, location: @employee }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /employees/1
  # DELETE /employees/1.json
  def destroy
    @employee.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to employees_url, notice: 'Employee was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_employee
      @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def employee_params
      if params[:employee][:password].blank? && params[:employee][:password_confirmation].blank?
          params[:employee].delete(:password)
          params[:employee].delete(:password_confirmation)
      end
      params[:employee].permit(:email, :password, :employee_id,:employee_work_id, :first_name, :middle_name, :last_name, :gender, :date_of_birth, :driver_license_no, :driver_license_expiry_date, :martial_status, :nationality, :office_address, :residence_address, :city, :state_province, :zip_code, :country, :work_number, :mobile_number, :home_number, :other_email)

    end
end
```

app/controllers/insurance_controller.rb:

```
class InsurancesController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_insurance, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      respond_to :html

      def index
        @insurances = Insurance.all
        respond_with(@insurances)
      end

      def show
        respond_with(@insurance)
      end

      def new
        @insurance = Insurance.new
        respond_with(@insurance)
      end

      def edit
      end

      def create
        @insurance = Insurance.new(insurance_params)
        @insurance.save
        respond_with(@insurance)
      end

      def update
        @insurance.update(insurance_params)
        respond_with(@insurance)
      end

      def destroy
        @insurance.destroy
        respond_with(@insurance)
      end

      private
        def set_insurance
          @insurance = Insurance.find(params[:id])
        end

        def insurance_params
          params.require(:insurance).permit(:employee_id,:name_of_dependent, :relationship, :name, :of_spouse, :children, :date_of_birth, :policy_number, :policy_provider, :policy_type)
        end
    end
```

app/views/insurances/_show.html.erb:

```
    <%= employee.insurances.each do |emp| %>
    <p>
      <strong>Name of dependent:</strong>
      <%= emp.name_of_dependent %>
    </p>

    <p>
      <strong>Name:</strong>
      <%= emp.name %>
    </p>
<% end %>
```

When i use link_to with show path, it is working fine.

app/views/employees/show.html.haml:

```
 %p
      %strong Title:
      = @employee.full_name
    %p
      %strong Text:
      = @employee.gender
    %p
      = link_to 'Insurance', insurance_path
```

after accordion code, i used render as follows:

```
  %p
      %strong Title:
      = @employee.full_name
    %p
      %strong Text:
      = @employee.gender
    %p
  #accordion2.panel-group
    #new-student-widget.panel.panel-default.left-column-entry
      .header.panel-heading
        .header-content.panel-title
          %a#newStudentToggle{"data-parent" => "#accordion2", "data-target" => "#newStudent", "data-toggle" => "collapse"} Insurance Details
      #newStudent.panel-collapse.collapse
        #newStudentInner.panel-body
          = render :template => 'insurances/show', locals: { employee: @employee }
```

When i am using render in accordion, i am getting error as:
**NoMethodError in Employees#show
undefined method `name_of_dependent' for nil:NilClass**
Please help me out.

Comment: Can you add the `show` template and the relevant controller code please.

Comment: insurances/show added. I'm new to rails please help me out

Comment: Could you please show us the ```Insurance``` controller ?

Comment: added Insurance controller

Comment: Employee has_one insurance or has_many insurances ?

Comment: employee has_many insurances

Comment: Then you need to loop through each insurance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling show as partial then rename show.html to _show.html
and pass @employeee instance variable which is present in accordion code

```
= render :template => 'insurances/show', locals: { employee: @employee }
```

and in _show page

```
- employee.insurances.each do |ins|
    %p.strong Name of dependent:
    = ins.name_of_dependent
    %p.strong Name:
    = ins.name
```

Comment: Sontya, making database call by ```employee.insurances```  from view is a bad practice. You have your controllers to do so!

Comment: Sharvy, thanks for specifying that I just ignored that, but then he has to pass two varibales in locals employee and insurances. And in your code you can use eager loading in controller with the help of `includes`

Comment: @rajkiran - what do you mean by accordion code, and when you are calling show page from show action in insurances controller, why are you again calling it as partial `= render :template => 'insurances/show'`

Comment: @Sontya - when i click on "Insurance Details" on accordion tab, i want display show page in it, so i am using render. When i simply used link_to and show path, it is working fine. The problem is with render. Is there any alternative for this?

Comment: make `_show.html.erb` to `_show.haml` and update the code accordingly in haml format as you are using haml, then check in you _show file `emp` value its has `name_of_dependent` or not

Comment: @Sontya - added `= render :partial => 'insurances/show', locals: { employee: @employee }` in employees\show.html.haml and changed insurances/_show.html.erb to haml code. It is showing empty array **[]** as a result.

Comment: employee.insurances is giving [] empty array right?, if yes then see employee has insurances or not on console

Comment: @Sontya - :employee_id is taken as 0 for all the records. Please help.

Comment: Have you addes employee_id as foreign key in insurance table

Comment: I just added : 
`rails g migration AddEmployeeToInsurance employee:references`. That's all. Is there anything need to be added

Comment: @rajkiran hope you have run `rake db:migrate`

Comment: @Sontya - i run rake db:drop, create and migrate. But the parent id (employee_id) is not passed to the child(insurance table)

Comment: @Sontya - i run rake db:drop, create and migrate. But the parent id (employee_id) is not passed to the child(insurance table)

first i run 
`rails g migration AddEmployeeToInsurance employee:references`
and then `rails g migration add_employee_id_to_insurance employee_id:string`

Comment: `rails g migration AddEmployeeIdToInsurance employee_id:integer` run this, employee_id should be integer and then `rake db:migrate`

Comment: still. It is taking employee_id as nil

Comment: check when you are creating insurance record, `insurance_params` you are passing `employee_id` or not if yes, then check errors on `Insurance` model

Comment: @Sontya - need to add anything else in Insurances controller?

Comment: `@insurance = @employee.insurances.create(insurance_params)` if you have @employee object in insurance controller this should work

Comment: I am getting **undefined method `insurances' for nil:NilClass**  error. I used  `@insurance = @employee.insurances.create(insurance_params)` in create method in Insurance controller and in insurance_params, i am using `params.require(:insurance).permit(:employee_id,:name_of_dependent, :name)`

Comment: In that case you should first find employee `@employee = Employee.find(params[:employee_id])` then call that line of code

Comment: **Couldn't find Employee without an ID**  is the error i am getting

Comment: @rajkiran - Please check what are the params you are getting, it has `employee_id` or not, then provide that `employee_id` to  `@employee = Employee.find(your_employee_id_from_params)`

Comment: @Sontya - Alas it's working. Thanks a lot for your patience :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `insurance` object when you are rendering the template :

```
- @insurances.each do |insurancce|
  = render template: 'insurances/show', locals: { insurance: insurance }
- end
```

Make sure you instantiated the `@insurance` object in your controller action, where you instantiated the `@employee` object.

```
@employee = current_user # or anything else
@insurances = @employee.insurances
```

Then in your `Insurances#show` template use `insurance` instead of `@insurance` like this :

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
<p>
  <strong>Name of dependent:</strong>
  <%= insurance.name_of_dependent %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= insurance.name %>
</p>
```

Comment: getting **undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass** error  in show

Comment: @rajkiran it's because you are not setting the `@insurances` variable in your controller.

Comment: You can see my code, there is @insurances variable.

Comment: Could you please show us the employees controller ?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed i added employees controller. When I used your solution,   i am getting [] as output.

Comment: Please add ```@insurances = @employee.insurances``` in your show action in employees controller, I'm seeing you haven't added that.

Comment: What is response of Employee.last.insurnaces in your rails console ?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed - i am  getting the error as **NoMethodError: undefined method `insurances' for #<User:0x4c7e968>**.

Comment: So the association didn't work. Do you have employee_id field in your insurances table?

Comment: @SharvyAhmed - i run rake db:drop, create and migrate. But the parent id (employee_id) is not passed to the child(insurance table)

first i run 
`rails g migration AddEmployeeToInsurance employee:references`
and then `rails g migration add_employee_id_to_insurance employee_id:string`

Comment: @rajkiran, you do  not need to do both, any one of those migrations will do the work. Then change your employees#new action into this : 
`@employee = Employee.new`
`@insurance = @employee.insurance.build`